# Finite topological space - basis

Tags: general-topology

Question: "Show that in a finite topological space, all the points have a neighborhood basis which which has one unique neighborhood."

My try:
For all points x in the space S i want to prove that there is a neighborhood basis with only one neighborhood.
What you would sugest for the basis? I am thinking that the basis has just a set which is open. But then i cannot do anything because i dont have enough information of this basis

Can you give some hints?

thanks!

Comment: Having a topological space means you have all the open sets.  From those open sets you are asked to construct a *neighborhood basis* such that each point (of which there are only finitely many) has a *unique* basis set containing it.

Comment: Suppose $U$ is an open neighborhood of $x\in S$. What does it mean for $\{U\}$ to be  a neighborhood basis for $x$?

Comment: it has to follows the two properties of the basis of neighborhoods...ok...but how this helps to prove the uniqueness?

Comment: @pipita Based on your comment, I think the word "unique" is throwing you off - the question is asking to show that each point $x$ in a finite space has a neighborhood basis with one element, that is, of the form $\{U\}$ for one $U$.

Comment: You didn't address your reply @ me so I only saw it now by accident. Anyway, OK, but I meant: what are those properties? State them, write them out; it will tell you the requirements that $U$, and should help you define a suitable $U$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a **neighborhood basis** of a point $x$ is a family of open sets $U_i$, each containing $x$, such that for any *other* open set $V$ containing $x$ we have $U_i\subseteq V$ for some $i$.

For instance, the set $\{(-a, a): a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\}$ forms a neighborhood basis for $0$ in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Meanwhile, $0$ has no *one-element* neighborhood basis: for any specific open set $U$ containing $x$, we can find a slightly smaller $V$ containing $x$ - for instance, $V=\{{x\over 2}: x\in U\}$ so long as $U$ is bounded.

The question is asking us to show that in a finite space, this "shrinking" can't happen: given any point $x$, we can find an open set containing $x$ which is "small enough" . . .

Does this help?